# I have 2 images in container background and foreground. How can I make foreground image responsive

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I have 2 images. 1 I have set in the background and another is showing above that background image, is responsive, but the foreground image is going wrong when I drag the browser to small. Site link is below.
https://padovasitiweb.it/test-page/

I have attached the code. I've put the foreground image on .title_container: before which is showing perfect but not responsive.

```
        .title_container:before {
background: url(https://padovasitiweb.it/wp-content/uploads/main-cover_fgg.png) no-repeat center center / cover;
content: '';
top: auto;
position: absolute;
bottom: 7px;
height: 360px;
width: 100%;
left: 0px;
z-index: 5;
text-align: center;
}
.title_container h1.entry-title{
margin-top: 7vw;
margin-bottom: 7vw;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
.title_container h1.entry-title, .title_container .entry-title a {
font-size: 8vw !important;
letter-spacing: -1px;
color: #333333!important;
top: 4px;

}
.title_container:before{
    height: 107px!important;    
    bottom: 2px !important;
}

}
```

I am expecting someone to help me find what I am missing in the code. I have set the media query for mobile, that's fine but not responsive for all devices. Foreground image should be equally shortened with the background when I drag browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cover` background size is causing the issue. The `cover` CSS property is more of a best fit style and doesn't fit to the width of it's parent. You can use percentages instead like `background-size: 100% auto;`, which will scale to the width of the parent with `100%` and retain it's aspect ratio with `auto`.

I have also changed the positioning from fixed units to percentages so it stays in the right place.

The only changes I made were to the styles in the `.container h1.entry-title:before` CSS property.

```
.container h1.entry-title:before {
    background: url(https://padovasitiweb.it/wp-content/uploads/main-cover_fgg.png) no-repeat center bottom;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 1.5%;
    left: 50.6%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
```

**EDIT**
I think you made a change to the HTML while I was looking at it. When I looked at the HTML, the `:before` element was a direct child of the element with the classes `stretch_full container_wrap alternate_color light_bg_color title_container`.

If you keep the HTML as it is now, you will also need to do the following CSS changes:

1) Apply `position:static` to the parent of the `:before` element with the classes `main-title entry-title`

2) Apply `position:static` to the parent of the `main-title entry-title` element with the class `container`

3) Apply `position:relative` to the parent of the `container` element with the classes `stretch_full container_wrap alternate_color light_bg_color title_container`

P.S. Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: thanks its working but on mobile its going little small in height and down to bottom. how can i control that ? using media query ?